# sbin/init crash after log in

Tags: 12.04, upstart, system, crash

Hi I have been getting a problem where, every time I log into Ubuntu, a red exclamation mark appears in the top-right of the screen.  On clicking it, a window appears to say "Sorry, Ubuntu 12.04 has experienced an internal error".  Here are some of the information also given.

======================================
ExecutablePath
   /sbin/init

Package
upstart 1.5-0ubuntu7.2 [modified: sbin/initctl]

ProblemType
Crash

Title
init crashed with SIGSEGV

ApportVersion
2.0.1-0ubuntu17.8

Architecture
i386

.
.
.

ProcCmdline
/sbin/init

UnreportableReason
This is not an official Ubuntu package.  Please remove any third party package and try again.

UpgradeStatus
No upgrade log present (probably fresh install)

=========================================================

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Maybe try running `dpkg --force-all --remove upstart` then running `apt-get install upstart`.

Answer (score -1):

In order to fix the error "Sorry, Ubuntu 12.04 has experienced an internal error" run the below command in the terminal,

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/apport
```

After running the command change the enabled parameter from 1 to 0 and then save the changes. Once you are done please reboot the machine, this might help you to fix.

Comment: This is just ignoring the problem. Do not do this.